# My response in Volley request always get into Error Listener

Tags: android, json, android-volley, response

i am using volly for json response this is my java code i tried every thing but unable to find error in it. it always go to  Error Listener.i really dont know why my response goes to error listener any body help me please thanks in advance

```
private void userLoign() {
    name = Name_Et.getText().toString();
    email = Email_Et.getText().toString();
    password = Password_Et.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "enter in userlogin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

   String URL = "added-platters.000webhostapp.com/application/index.php";

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "enter in Volley", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                int success = jObj.getInt("value");
                Log.e("value in success", String.valueOf(success));

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Log.i("myTag", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("myTag", error.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("tag", "Register");
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("lat", "1234");
            params.put("log", "1234");

            return params;
        }
    };
    myReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            20000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    ));
    myReq.setShouldCache(false);
    queue.add(myReq);

}
```

and this is my json response in php

```
{"value":"Record Inserted Successfully"}
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("myTag", error.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })

Comment: Need Logcat Error not code

Comment: there is no error in catlog

Comment: it just enter in onErrorResponse with out any error

Comment: Add error.printstacktrace() onErrorResponse method

Comment: this is my catlog

Comment: Protocol not found: added-platters.000webhostapp.com/application/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is URL Protocol not specified

```
String URL = "added-platters.000webhostapp.com/application/index.php";
```

to

```
String URL = "http://added-platters.000webhostapp.com/application/index.php";
```